# What type of data is this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data, categorical-data

I am doing an analysis on the unit sales of mobile phones. There a two categories of phones that I am comparing, the first is iphone 6 and the other is samsung S6.
Now I have different models in each category and I have coded them as 1 for iphone 6plus, 2 for iphone 6 64 gig, 3 for another model of iphone 6. I did the same for the s6 models as well. My question is, when it comes to hypothesis testing for these data, I cannot move on unless I am sure exactly what type of data this is, interval, nominal or ordinal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nominal.

- Nominal/Categorical data is the most general case of discrete data.
- Ordinal data has some ordering from least to greatest (child, adult, senior)
- Interval data is ordered and the possible values are evenly separated (age in years).